# Trouble moving uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload

I am simply trying to move an uploaded file to a location on my server. Here is my code.

```
    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "img/uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['imageURL']['tmp_name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageURL']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file has been moved";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error.";
    }
```

I keep getting the error for false and I can't figure out why it won't move it. I've verified the location of it with an if statement it results in true.

I edited the name path for the tmp_name in the array..still hasn't worked. I did a dump and I have no tmp_key for that array. Why am I not getting the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_FILES['imageURL']['name']` is the **name** of the file, not the **location** in the OS-temp directory.

I think you need to use `$_FILES['imageURL']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: I'm still getting the error even though I changed it. I did a var_dump on the $_FILES array and there is no temporary name key. This is the problem I think.

Comment: Check the value of `$_FILES['imageURL']['error']`. Compare with the globals on http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php to see if anything else goes wrong.

Comment: It is error number 1 which means the php.ini needs to be changed. This is the correct answer right?

Comment: Not directly, it means the filesize is larger than the `upload_max_filesize` setting. If you want to accept larger files, increase the value of that setting.

Comment: I now am getting an error of 0, but it still is throwing me back the error of false.

Comment: Does the destination exist and is it writable? If you turn on notices with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` you should get a better error message.

Comment: Its giving me a permission denied error, but on the upload directory it has a permission of 755.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19170/discussion-between-wowzuzz-and-frits-van-campen)